# How do I make insert query to insert records in batches in DB2?

Tags: database, unix, db2, insertion

I have 2 tables lets say A & B. I want to insert table B data to table A in a batch manner. For example I want to insert only 100 rows per execution of insert query.

Comment: Can you please add an explanation of why you want to do this to your question?

Comment: actually the bulk insertion at a time is taking too much of time and not making DB free to other processes

Comment: Are you copying the entire table?

Comment: yes. I am copying all the data from table B to table A

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination on the `select` query on the source table to limit the results you get each time and insert in batches.  There are several possible approaches, [which this article discusses](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/SQLTips4DB2LUW/entry/limit_offset?lang=en).

However, if you just want to copy an entire table from one location to another, you should probably use [`load table`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0008305.html) from a cursor instead.  This will be much, much faster.  See [another DB2 article explaining how to do this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0901fechner/).

Some other strategies for speeding up large inserts (which work even if you aren't copying an entire table):

- Disable logging on the destination table with [`activate not logged initially`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/c0006079.html). *Use with caution (and only when appropriate), as if anything goes wrong, the table is in an unrecoverable state and must be recreated!*
- [Set the locking on the destination table to `locksize table`](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000888.html).  This will block this table from being used during the insert, but it will prevent a database lock from being created for each row that is inserted, which can increase performance.

*Note: documentation links were to whatever DB2 version I could find easily.  Make sure you check the docs for your own version, as there are some pretty big differences between versions.*

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!. This helps